# SignalR 2 MVC 5 NTLM

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr, ntlm

I make app from this tutorial(http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc) and it work fine.

But now I want use NTLM, and website on first run, start but I have null in $.connection.CommunicationsHub; //CommunicationsHub is a name of my hub

And next time when I run a solution webbrowser have status:" Waiting for host" and I can wait all day.

I run a App on Microsoft edge and Firefox.
Startup class:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(ASPMVC.Startup.Startup))]

namespace ASPMVC.Startup
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
        Debug.WriteLine("----------> Startup Configuration");
        app.MapSignalR();

        }

    }
```

}
(path: Root/Hubs/CommunicationsHub.cs)
hub claas make like in tutorial:

```
namespace ASPMVC.Hubs
{
   public class CommunicationsHub : Hub
   {
      public void Send(string name, string message)
      {
        Debug.WriteLine("---------->"+name);
        //Call the addNewMessageToPage method to update clients.
        Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(name, message);
       }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add custom name to your hub?

```
namespace ASPMVC.Hubs
{
   [HubName("CommunicationsHub")]
   public class CommunicationsHub : Hub
   {
      public void Send(string name, string message)
      {
        Debug.WriteLine("---------->"+name);
        //Call the addNewMessageToPage method to update clients.
        Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(name, message);
       }
   }
 }
```